# Como chamar uma função auxilar sem passar o parâmetro pela função principal

Tags: haskell

Eu estou tentando resolver alguns problemas básicos de haskell, mas estou com uma dificuldade. Eu implementei o seguinte código:

```
type Nome = String
type Preco = Int
type CodigoBarra = Int
type BancoDeDados = [(CodigoBarra, Nome, Preco)]

bd:: BancoDeDados
bd = [(1001,"Refrigerante",450),
     (1002,"Leite",320),
     (1003,"Biscoito",200),
     (1004,"Suco",989),
     (1005,"Arroz",345),
     (1006,"Feijao",780)]

buscarBDaux:: CodigoBarra->BancoDeDados->(Nome,Preco)
buscarBDaux cd ((a,b,c):d) |a == cd = (b,c) 
                           |otherwise = buscarBDaux cd d
```

Agora eu preciso implementar a função `buscarDB`,que funcionaria assim:

Entrada: `buscarDB 1006`
Saída: `("Feijao", 780)`

Essa função usaria a `buscarBDaux`, mas eu não estou conseguindo chamar `buscarBDaux` sem ter passado o banco de dados no `buscarDB`. Poderiam me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como você mesmo percebeu, você deve chamar o banco de alguma forma. A solução mais comum fazer uso de *currying* e `flip` com a função `buscarDBaux` para cirar `buscarDB`, ou reordenar os argumentos de `buscarDBaux` para não precisar usar `flip`:

```hs
-- Usando flip
-- flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
buscarDB :: CodigoBarra -> (Nome, Preco)
buscarDB = flip buscarDBaux db

-- Redefinindo buscarDBaux
buscarDBaux :: BancoDeDados -> CodigoBarra -> (Nome, Preco)
buscarDBaux ((a,b,c):d) cd 
    | a == cd   = (b,c) 
    | otherwise = buscarBDaux cd d

buscarDB :: CodigoBarra -> (Nome, Preco)    
buscarDB = buscarDBaux db
```

A vantagem desse método é que você pode criar várias funções individuais para cada banco de dados, caso precise. Por exemplo, se você tiver `db1`, `db2` e `db3`, é possível fazer:

```
-- Usando buscarDBaux redefinido
buscarDB1 = buscarDBaux db1
buscarDB2 = buscarDBaux db2
buscarDB3 = buscarDBaux db3
```

Ou criar uma lista de funções de busca usando `zipWith ($)`:

```
buscas :: [CodigoBarra -> (Nome, Preco)]
buscas = zipWith ($) (repeat buscarDBaux) [db1, db2, db3]
```

Recomendo que leia alguma material sobre funções de alta ordem e *currying*:

- [Wikibook Haskell: Listas II#Curry](https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Listas_II#Caso_geral)
- [LYaHfGG: Funções de alta ordem#Funções *curried*](http://haskell.tailorfontela.com.br/higher-order-functions#curried-functions)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda luispauloml, resolveu meu problema.